# Sequelize join and limit

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to form a query with Sequelize to join and select + limit. Let me illustrate the problem:

I have a Many-to-Many relationship: `Book` - `Reader`. A reader can have many books and a book can have many readers.

Given the id of a `Book`, I would like to page through all of its `Reader`s.
Here's what I currently have tried, it has some issues. First the paging does not work. Second it still selects all the attributes of `Book` as well as `Reader`, when I only need `Reader` (I'm throwing away all of `Book`).

```
/**
 * Get all Readers of a Book.
 *
 * @param {Number} bookId id of the book
 * @param {Number} limit number of readers to retrieve
 * @param {Number} offset number of readers to skip 
 * @return {Promise} contains an array of readers
 */
function getBookReaders(bookId, limit, offset) {
  return Book.findOne({
    id: bookId,
    include: [Reader],
    limit: 10,
    offset: 30
  }).then(function(book) {
    return book.readers;
  });
}
```

Any suggestions on how to form this query correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this actually works, but it would make sense to apply the limit to the model you want to limit:

```
Book.findOne({
  id: bookId,
  include: [ { model: Reader, limit: 10, offset: 30 } ]
}).then(function(book) {
  return book.readers;
});
```

Comment: the limit/offset still did not work, the [API docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#findalloptions-queryoptions-promisearrayinstance) don't list limit/offset options for nested include models

Comment: Yep. There seems to be a feature request for that, but right now there doesn't seem to be any way of doing that without querying twice. But since you know the reference you can make both queries run in parallel with Promise.all().

Comment: Sorry, didn't follow that, how would I do this in parallel? It's a many-to-many model, so I need the join table to get all the `Reader`'s ids / I can't query `Reader` table directly.

Comment: Hmm... The many-to-many could pose a problem, but you could invert the query and still get both the book and the readers: Reader.findAll({ include [ { model: Book, where: { id: bookId }, required: true } ], limit: 10, offset: 30 });

Comment: Still had some issues there, ended up going with a raw query to also only select what I needed.